# Change url of site in wordpress.com

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress.com

I have created site in wordpress.com running on url http://abcd.com now i want to change that url to http://www.abcd.com   how this can be done in wordpress.com.

Comment: do you have access for .htaccess file?

Comment: no i have no access for file i am only having wordpress.com  admin panel

Comment: added an answer, take a look

Comment: i have checked your answer. i want my godday domain to map with wordpress.com  then also it removes www from site  url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think so you can add www redirect in wordpress.com,

take a look at the comment from wordpress.com forum

> I’m sorry but there is no fix. WordPress.com automatically removes the
>   “www” from all URLs.
>
> The software here will strip out the www. out and always seamlessly
>   redirect to the URL without the “www”.
>
> www is an old protocol from back when everything was under separate
>   server hardware. www (www.example.com) was the web server, mail
>   (mail.example.com) was the mail server, ftp (ftp.example.com) was the
>   FTP server, print (print.example.com) was the print server, etc. These
>   days, everything is run under the web server, making www. redundant
>   and a waste of four characters.

[more info](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/www-redirect-1/)

[more info about www redirect](https://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/custom-domain-www-redirect/)

Answer (score -1):

```
        **INSTRUCTIONS**

        Via WordPress Dashboard
        1.After moving your site files (if necessary), log into your your WordPress Dashboard as an administrator.
        2.Next, click on Settings from the menu, and then General.
        3.The two fields we'll change are WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL).
        4.Enter the URL you'd like to use. For this example, we'll change the two fields to http://example.com.
        5.Scroll down the page and click on the Save Changes button.
        6.Be sure that you rename the folder to the new URL in FTP or the File Manager. 

    OR

    YOU can changed it from phpmyadmin.
- Move in your wordpress database.
- Search for wp_option.
- Then search for "siteurl" and changed option_value of it.
```